InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type '...Context' while attempting to activate
My project is being built with asp.net core razor pages and dotnet 7
I have considered a separate layer for the database and my database is built in the Database First method

The connection string is written in appsettings.json and added to the services through program.cs in data layer
Then, in the application layer, I referenced the data layer and added the following command in program.cs in the app layer
builder.Services.AddScoped<DbkabirContext, DbkabirContext>();
This is Program.cs in Data Layer:
and my connection string is in appsettings.json with name DbkabirConnectionString
using KabirLang.Data.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbkabirContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer("Name=DbkabirConnectionString");
});
var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();

and this is Program.cs in App Layer:
using KabirLang.Data.Models;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddScoped<DbkabirContext, DbkabirContext>();
var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();

After running the program in the page model, I get a null value from the context:

I have two questions and please guide me:
1- What is the cause of the error and where is the problem in my work?
2- This method that I have placed the database, models and connection in a separate layer from the application layer and referred to the application layer, is it a suitable method for the security and stability of the software database and do you recommend it or not?
thanks
And if I remove this code builder.Services.AddScoped<DbkabirContext, DbkabirContext>();
from program.cs in app layer, I get the following error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'KabirLang.Data.Models.DbkabirContext' while attempting to activate 'KabirLang.Pages.LevelTestListModel'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)


Entiryframework core doesn't need "AddScoped<DbkabirContext, DbkabirContext>();"
And actually the dependency injection usage should be db=context not "context=db". "db" is the new instance you create in the controller.
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0#overview-of-dependency-injection


Why you have different Program.cs files? You should have only one.
AddScoped<DbkabirContext, DbkabirContext>(); is not necessary

And, you are doing:
context = db;

Instead of:
db = context;

Because context will be injected from outside.
